# Error during installation of Jasper Reportt Server

Tags: installation, keystore, jasperserver, windows-11

I'm trying to install Jasper Report Server but I keep getting always the same error: during the post-install actions I get the following

```
    Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly 
 
Error running C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0/buildomatic/js-ant.bat
 
load-sugarcrm-db:[create-ks] Failed to create the keystore C:\Users\Paolo\.jrsks
 
BUILD FAILED
 
C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0\buildomatic\build.xml:377: The
 
following error occurred while executing this line:
 
C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0\buildomatic\bin\setup.xml:377:
 
Keystore may have been tampered with.
 
Total time: 1 second
```

I'm using the default installation and windows 11. I also tried running it in compatibility mode for Windows 7 but nothing changed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that js-install.sh created the keystore and placed it in a user directory, where it then couldn't access it again.

You could check the access rights for the folder the keystore is placed, and check if your user has the right ones.